# JQuery - How to keep a link selected after the form has been submitted

Tags: php, jquery

I was wondering how can I keep a link selected once I submit my form and the data is displayed back to me. I basically want to know how to keep my link highlighted after I submit my form data using jQuery or PHP if possible.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editor, .active-editor').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings().addClass('text-editor').removeClass('active-text-editor');
        $(this).addClass('active-editor').removeClass('editor');        
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this making a full round trip (the page refreshes) or are you dynamically loading content back into the page (like ajax)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link to appear as if it is in the "active" state you can create a style named a.active that shares the same rules as a:active (the active link psuedo-class) and dynamically apply that class.  Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SM22n/2/

If you want a link to appear active after the page has been reloaded then you'll likely have to set some query parameter that informs your script that the link should appear active. Here's a simple example using PHP which searches for the presence of a parameter named "success" and adds the class "active" to the link if present:

```
<?php $myClass = isset($_GET['success']) ? 'active' : ''; ?>
<a href="http://example.com" class="<?php echo $myClass; ?>">My Link</a>
```